# How to concat two python DataFrames where if the row already exits it doesn't add it, if not, append it

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm pretty new to python.
I am trying to concat two dataframes (df1, df2) where if a row already exists in df1 then it is not added. if not, it adds to df1.
I don't want to use .concat().drop_duplicates() because I don't want duplicates within the same DataFrame to be removed.

BackStory: 
I have multiple csv files that are exported from a software in different locations once in a while I want to merge these into one file. the problem is the exported files will have the same data as before along with the new records made within that period of time. therefore I need to check if the record is already in there as I will be executing the same code each time I export the data.

for the sake of example:

```
import pandas as pd
main_df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[4,2,5,1],[2,4,1,5],[2,5,4,5],[9,8,7,6],[8,5,6,7]])
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[4,2,5,1],[2,4,1,5],[1,5,4,8],[7,3,5,7],[4,3,8,5],[4,3,8,5]])
```

```
main_df
    0   1   2   3
0   1   2   3   4   --duplicates I want to include--
1   1   2   3   4   --duplicates I want to include--
2   4   2   5   1
3   2   4   1   5
4   2   5   4   5
5   9   8   7   6
6   8   5   6   7

df1
    0   1   2   3
0   1   2   3   4  --duplicates I want to exclude--
1   1   2   3   4  --duplicates I want to exclude--
2   4   2   5   1  --duplicates I want to exclude--
3   2   4   1   5  --duplicates I want to exclude--
4   1   5   4   8
5   7   3   5   7
6   4   3   8   5  --duplicates I want to include--
7   4   3   8   5  --duplicates I want to include--
```

I need the end result to be

```
main_df (after code execution)

    0   1   2   3
0   1   2   3   4
1   1   2   3   4
2   4   2   5   1
3   2   4   1   5
4   2   5   4   5
5   9   8   7   6
6   8   5   6   7
7   1   5   4   8
8   7   3   5   7
9   4   3   8   5
10  4   3   8   5
```

I hope I have explained my issue in a clear way. Thank you

Comment: `result = pd.concat([main_df, df1], axis=1, ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates(keep='first')`

Comment: @PV8 This will drop duplicates within the same DataFrame which I don't want to happen. plus axis=1 will add new columns which is not what I'm looking for. any other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Check for every row in df1 whether it exists in main_df using pandas apply, and turn that into a mask by negating it with the `~` operator. I like using [functools partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to make explicit that we are comparing to main_df.

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import partial
main_df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1,2,3,4],
    [1,2,3,4],
    [4,2,5,1],
    [2,4,1,5],
    [2,5,4,5],
    [9,8,7,6],
    [8,5,6,7]
])
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    [1,2,3,4],
    [1,2,3,4],
    [4,2,5,1],
    [2,4,1,5],
    [1,5,4,8],
    [7,3,5,7],
    [4,3,8,5],
    [4,3,8,5]
])

def has_row(df, row):
    return (df == row).all(axis = 1).any()

main_df_has_row = partial(has_row, main_df)

duplicate_rows = df1.apply(main_df_has_row, axis = 1)

df1_add = df1.loc[~duplicate_rows]

pd.concat([main_df, df1_add])
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I have to admit though I don't understand what happened I have to go through it few times to wrap my head around it. seems like I still have ALOT to learn.